# Parsing a CSV string in Shell Script and writing it to a File

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I am not a Linux scripting expert and I have exhausted my knowledge on this matter. Here is my situation.

I have a list of states passed as a command line argument to a shell script ( e.g "AL,AK,AS,AZ,AR,CA..." ). The Shell script needs to extract each of the state code and write it to a file ( states.txt) , with each state in one line. See below

```
AL
AK
AS
AZ
AR
CA
..
..
```

How can this be achieved using a linux shell script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use `tr`:

```
echo "AL,AK,AS,AZ,AR,CA" | tr ',' '\n' > states.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "AL,AK,AS,AZ,AR,CA" | awk -F, '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $i}';
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution:

```
echo "AL,AK,AS,AZ,AR,CA" | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think awk is the simplest solution, but you could try using `cut` in a loop.
Sample script (outputs to stdout, but you can just redirect it):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for input
if (( ${#1} == 0 )); then
  echo No input data supplied
  exit
fi

# Initialise first input
i=$1

# While $i still contains commas
while { echo $i| grep , > /dev/null; }; do
  # Get first item of $i
  j=`echo $i | cut -d ',' -f '1'`

  # Shift off the first item of $i
  i=`echo $i | cut --complement -d ',' -f '1'`

  echo $j
done

# Display the last item
echo $i
```

Then you can just run it as `./script.sh "AL,AK,AS,AZ,AR,CA" > states.txt` (assuming you save it as script.sh in the local directory and give it execute permission)